# I Want to Put String on URL for HTTP CLIENT API LARAVEL 8

Tags: laravel-8

my View :

```
<td>{{ $b = $booking->tanggal_pemesanan }}</td>
```

`<td><a href="/{{ $b }}">CEK</a></td>`

Route :
`Route::get('/{b}', [TestController::class, 'index']);`

my Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    return Http::get('https://wetonizer-api.herokuapp.com/{b}');
}
```

did i do wrong? please help....

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual return of $booking->tanggal_pemesanan?

Try using;

```
<td><a href="/{{ $booking->tanggal_pemesana }}">CEK</a></td>
```

In your Controller;

index function should have ($b) to understand/know what is {b}

Then it should work